# Replace character "\" with "\\"?

Tags: python-3.x, file, replace, decode, codec

When I copy a path from Windows explorer, it will be in this `"C:\Users"` notation, while I actually want `"C:\\Users"`. Is there some function that does this replacement for me?

I already figured out that the other way round can be solved using `codecs.decode(file_path, "unicode_escape")`, not sure about this direction though.

Comment: Paste where? Into Python code? In this case, use a raw string: `r"<paste path here>"`. Otherwise, if you paste it into `input` or a UI textfield, Python will do the escaping for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by [tobias_k in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621857/replace-character-with/63226178#comment74292810_43621857), use a raw string:

> In this case, use a raw string: `r"<paste path here>"`. Otherwise, if you paste it into `input` or a UI textfield, Python will do the escaping for you.